# php date choose from drop down list min and max

Tags: php, date

i have this code:

```
<tr><td>Data expirare:</td><td><?=date_chooser("date",date("Y-m-d"),0)?></td></tr>
```

It is working properly, but at the moment I look from 1920 until 2050 and I want to show me only of certain pending and the next five years.

Comment: You need to tell more about the date_chooser function. There is nothing we can do to answer your question with so little details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using the date_chooser() algorithm from this SO post: [How to jump to anchor on submit - not to top of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715387/how-to-jump-to-anchor-on-submit-not-to-top-of-page) or this internet page: http://ideone.com/Ab0cLD

I adapted a small part of the code by adding two variables: `$from_year` and `$to_year`. They do now define the range of the years in your drop down. You can the adapt the value of the variables to your needs.

```
$chooser.="<select name='".$name."year'>";
$from_year = 1950
$to_year = date("Y") + 5
   for($i=$from_year;$i<=$to_year;$i++)
   {
      if($i==$year) $selected='selected';
      else $selected='';
      $chooser.="<option $selected>$i</option>";
   }
```